# Using Flow designer how do I open a record for editing that was created within the same flow process

Tags: flow

I am using the Standard 'Order' object called Orders and have installed the Salesforce Labs 'Generate Orders' app.  The app generates a new Order from the Opportunity, pulling in specified fields (Close Date, etc.) - When the process is complete the Order has been created but the user is left on the Opportunity and must navigate to the Related Lists to find and open the new Order.  I want to have the process open the Order after it has been created so that the user can immediately start to fill in the Order (PO number, Amount, etc.) - Here is the flow...
[image: My Opportunity to Order Flow]

Answer (score 1):

If retrieve the created Order into an sObject variable, e.g. sovOrder, then you can create a screen after the Fast Update where the order is activated and use the fields on that screen to capture the Order details then Assign these fields to the relevant sObject and use another Fast Update to assign the updated sObject values to the Order record.

If you have any fields where you want to display values from the order you can set these as the Default values for those fields as follows:-

[image: default value]